# Difficulty returning a value from a Room Database

Tags: android, database, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I feel I'm so close to grasping this Room database thing.  I have the database running fine and I can add records, search and delete but I am unable to figure out how to Sum a column and use the result in my UI.

Here's my Dao

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(findAmount) FROM finds")
fun getFindTotal():String
```

Here's my Repository

```
fun getFindTotal():String {
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
val myVal = findDao.getFindTotal()
Log.i("myVal","The Value of myVal ${myVal}")
   }
return "Dummy String"
}
```

Here's my Viewmodel

```
fun getFindTotal():String {
var myTotal = repository.getFindTotal()
Log.i("myTotal", myTotal)
return myTotal
}
```

Here's my UI

```
var myTotal = viewModel.getFindTotal()
Text("Total = ${myTotal}")
```

I feel I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding with how Room works.

In my repository I used a Log.i to look at the value of the variable myVal, it is producing the correct value so my SQL query in my Dao must be working.  I cannot figure out how to return the value of myVal to the viewmodel so I used "Dummy String" to make sure the string is being passed.  It is, the UI produces Dummy String.

How do I pass the value of myVal to the viewmodel or am I going about this completely wrong?  I had a suggestion to use Flow, is that the best way to go about this?

Thank you very much for considering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways, `Flow` is indeed one of them. The best way really depends on your use case. Do you need the value to update when items are inserted/deleted? Flow is a must then. Do you need to call `getFindTotal` just once and then cache it in your ViewModel, or do you need to call it multiple times in response to some event?

Anyway, here are some suggestions to get you started:

```kotlin
// Room supports coroutines - make the function suspend or return Flow
// already in your dao

@Query("SELECT SUM(findAmount) FROM finds")
suspend fun getFindTotal(): Long // sum should probably return Long rather than String

@Query("SELECT SUM(findAmount) FROM finds")
fun getFindTotalFlow(): Flow<Long>
```

```kotlin
// your repository will then just delagate to dao, at least for now

suspend fun getFindTotal(): Long {
    return findDao.getFindTotal()
}

fun getFindTotalFlow(): Flow<Long> {
    return findDao.getFindTotalFlow()
}
```

```kotlin
// in your viewmodel, you can do something like this

val findTotalFlow: StateFlow<Long?> = repository.getFindTotalFlow().stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    initialValue = null,
)

// or this

suspend fun getFindTotal(): Long {
    // this adds 2s delay so you can actually see the progress in ui,
    // don't use in production ;)
    delay(2000)
    return repository.getFindTotal()
}
```

```kotlin
// finally, you can use it in your compose ui like this

@Composable fun Example(viewModel: YourViewModel) {
    // flow in combination with collectAsState will update your ui every
    // time the sum in database changes
    val currentFindTotal by viewModel.findTotalFlow.collectAsState()

    if (currentFindTotal != null) {
        Text("Current find total is $currentFindTotal")
    } else {
        Text("Waiting for the first value from database")
    }
}

// or like this

@Composable fun Example2(viewModel: YourViewModel) {
    var retrievedFindTotal by remember { mutableStateOf<Long?>(null) }
    var retrievalInProgress by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    if (retrievedFindTotal != null) {
        Text("Retrieved find total is $retrievedFindTotal")
    } else if (retrievalInProgress) {
        Text("Retrieval in progress!")
    } else {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    retrievalInProgress = true
                    retrievedFindTotal = viewModel.getFindTotal()
                    retrievalInProgress = false
                }
            }
        ) { Text("Start execution!") }
    }
}
```

Finally, I would suggest you study a bit more about asynchronous execution, why you need it when accessing database and how to do that in kotlin - coroutines and flows, so you have a clue what you are doing.